# How to download an archive of all posts on Piazza?

Tags: piazza

Piazza has no official feature to download all posts. I can't use `wget` to crawl the site, because although I can get past the login using a `cookies.txt` file, the entire interface is dynamically generated with javascript, which `wget` doesn't support. I tried using the [website-scraper-phantom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/website-scraper-phantom) nodejs package in addition to [cookies.txt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies.txt) to read the cookie file, but then it crawls the home page instead of the posts.

Comment: You could try using [httrack](https://forum.httrack.com/readmsg/29879/16174/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Piazza has a link in its Statistics page for exporting JSON/CSV class data to email, but it's never worked for me, even after contacting support. Edit: This option has since silently disappeared.

In the meantime: really quick hack using [automate-save-page-as](https://github.com/abiyani/automate-save-page-as):

```
for i in {001..100}; do 
    ./save_page_as -b firefox --save-wait-time 4 https://piazza.com/class/<class-id>/post/$i -d $i.html

    # optional: remove blank posts you don't have access to. Test this!
    grep -q postViewSummaryId $i.html || rm -r $i.html ${i}_files
done
```

This will try to access every post by ID in order, including ones you don't have access to (you may also want to save Resources and Statistics pages). You need to set Firefox or Chrome to save as "Web Page, complete" beforehand. Opening the HTML will give some JS error which is due to the page trying to access resources it doesn't have permissions to, which can be mitigated by prematurely stopping the page from rendering (all the HTML info in the post is still there).

For me, each saved page and associated folder of extra files totals about 9 MB, however since across pages these are largely redundant, the pages together compress very well with LZMA with a large enough dictionary (ex. default 7z, but not gzip with 32K dictionary).

This raw HTML is not very easy to grep because of all the embedded JS scripts and the sidebar duplicates a lot of Q&A content. For actual text searching I would filter `<div id="qanda-content">` with [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup), or more fancily use HTML inner text to get actual textual content. This also produces a much smaller HTML (kilobytes) but linked content like images require the corresponding `html_files` folder.